# How to disable tab bar in aquamacs

Tags: aquamacs

I've been trying for a bit to disable the tabbar mode in aquamacs: when I open a new file from one buffer, I'd like the file to open in the current buffer instead of opening the file in a new tab.

I've tried turning tabbar-mode off in my init.el file as follows:

```
(tabbar-mode 0)
```

but it doesn't seem to have any effect.  Does anyone know if disabling tabbed buffers in aquamacs is possible?  Please let me know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(tabbar-mode 0)
```

does actually work.  I had been editing the wrong file and that is why it wasn't taking effect.  For future users, ensure that you put the above line in `~/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/Preferences.el` (or one of the other packages that that file includes).